# How to freeze first row in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Can we freeze first row of the jqgrid? Is that possible?

My jqgrid contains customized combo boxes and input fields in the top row to add rows, and starting from the second row it displays data rows which we put in first row and added them.
 When I'm reaching maximum height of the grid, a vertical scrollbar enables to scroll and view bottom rows for the user. But when I have to add a new row, when I'm viewing my last row using scrollbar, I have to scroll all the way top to add it.
 So, I'm looking around for a solution to freeze the top row, where user don't need to scroll top whenever a new row is need to be added.
 I can see few solutions to freeze the columns by using inbuilt properties of jqgrid but I'm not able to find a way to freeze the rows.

Please let me know if there is any way to freeze it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Directly this is not supported. If this will solve the problem you can use a footer row which is frozen, but at footer. To place data here you will need to enable the footerrow and an use **footerData** method. See the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#options)

The below recommendation is just idea - In case you do not use searching  you can call  filterToolbar method, but in this case you will need to set search: false in all fileds in colModel. Doing this, you will have a frozen header data row.

Another possible solution is to use the method setGroupHeader [see here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#header-grouping):
The disadvantage of the solution is that the row is placed above the header rows.

**UPDATE:**

Below is the code assuming that filterToolbar will not be used for searching.
The my idea is with following steps:

1. Initially set the fields with search:false
2. call fileterToobar method. This will add a frozen header
3. Get the ids in order to get the first one.
4. Get the data from the first row and delete it from the grid.
5. Put the date in header (see how is the id buildes)
6. Set search to true in order to use the other search modules.

Using jsonstring and array data is the same, so I put here array data.

```
    var mydata = [
           { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
           { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
           { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
           { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
           { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
    ];


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            height: 250,
            width: 780,
            sortname : "amount",
            sortorder: "desc",
            colModel: [
                { label: 'Inv No', name: 'id', width: 75, key:true, search : false },
                { label: 'Date', name: 'invdate', width: 90, search : false },
                { label: 'Client', name: 'name', width: 100, search : false },
                { label: 'Amount', name: 'amount', width: 80, search : false },
                { label: 'Tax', name: 'tax', width: 80, search : false },
                { label: 'Total', name: 'total', width: 80, search : false },
                { label: 'Notes', name: 'note', width: 150, search : false }
            ],
            viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data rang and total records on the toolbar
            caption: "Load jqGrid through Javascript Array",
        });
        // call filterToolbar with serch false. This build the header
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("filterToolbar",{});
        // get the first id and the data
        var ids = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
        var first_id = ids[0];
        var first_row_data = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getRowData", first_id);
        // delete it
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("delRowData", first_id);
        // get colModel to get names
        var colModel = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        //console.log(colModel);
        for(var i=0, len= colModel.length; i<len; i++ ) {
            // set the header
            $("#gsh_jqGrid_"+colModel[i].name).html( first_row_data[colModel[i].name] );
            // set search to true in order to use the other search modules
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("setColProp", colModel[i], {search : true});
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the link [to the demo](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/support/headrow/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solutions/suggestions.1 and 3 solutions will not work in my case, since the first row of the grid should be frozen(below the header and above the footer). I will try with the 2nd recommendation. Thanks again.

Comment: @user10520600 I'm going to prepare a example, but I need to know what is your datatype - json(server side) or local (array)?

Comment: My datatype is jsonstring

Comment: Thanks for your example and sorry for my late reply. I have been trying to use your logic but it is not working for me. It's deleting the row from the grid but not showing up in the filter toolbar row. I'm not sure where I am going wrong but I assume that it is because of the jqGrid version? I have noticed that the version you used is 5.3 and the version what I am using is 4.13.                                                                    

Here is the example which I have tried using your logic https://jsfiddle.net/UserXR/wmg16uft/7/

Is there a way that we can do it with the v4.13?

Comment: free-jqGrid 4.13 is a fork of jqGrid and I can't guarantee that the code will work on 100% with it. The simplest that you can test is to execute my example with this version of free-jqGrid.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned earlier, I have executed your example with the free-jqGrid 4.13  here http://jsfiddle.net/UserXR/wmg16uft/7 and it did not worked as how it is for you. When I'm doing that, I noticed that when I use $("tr.ui-search-toolbar").html(first_row_data[colModel[i].name]) I can see the first row's data one by one showing up in the whole toolbar row while looping(with the debugger). But I cannot see that with $("#gs_"+colModel[i].name).html(first_row_data[colModel[i].name]). Am I going wrong somewhere or it's the issue with the version I'm using? Please let me know if you can. Thanks!